# Different line types in one ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I want to create a line graph in ggplot2 that contains different line types.

I tried it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

head(a)
a <- read.table(text = "m     A    B    C
1 Okt  9.250 14.75475  5.94375
2 Nov 10.343 16.21625  7.88050
3 Dez 14.885 25.81775 10.13550
4 Jan 15.566 25.17125 11.70950
5 Feb 15.619 22.53175 11.80400", header = TRUE)
a$m <- factor(a$m, levels = c("Okt", "Nov", "Dez", "Jan", "Feb"))

xy <- gather(a, key = variable, value = value, -m)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = m, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable))
```

But the plot doesn't show any lines at all. I would like the A line to be a solid line and B and C dashed lines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `group = variable` in your `aes`:

```r
ggplot(xy, aes(x = m, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable))
```

[image]

This is necessary because your `m` x-axis is a factor, not a continuous variable, meaning `geom_line` doesn't know to connect them.