# Cannot plot multiple lines with different linetype and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a ggplot2 with multiple lines with different line types and colors. I think I know how to change the color, but I keep having a hard time changing the line type.

please refer to the below code and explanation.

```
Multi_2000m <- Multi_Export %>% filter(CPTED_YR == '2'|CPTED_YR == '1'|CPTED_YR == '-1'|CPTED_YR == '-2')
SP <- Multi_2000m %>% ggplot(aes(x=CPTED_DIST, y=CPI_Price, color = CPTED_YR, group = CPTED_YR)) + geom_smooth(method="loess")
SP + geom_vline(xintercept=1000) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(7000, 12000))
```

[image]

This is what I get when I use the code on the top. As you can see, I have 3 variables; x=distance, y=price, and 4 line groups of CPTED_YR = -2, -1, 1, 2

From here, I want to change the color and the line type, not automatically, but in the following order:

- CPTED_YR = -2, longdash (5), blue
- CPTED_YR = -1, dashed (2), navy
- CPTED_YR = 1, solid (1), red
- CPTED_YR = 2, twodash (6), burgundy

so this is the color code and line type code that I tried. Based on the suggestion from the link at the bottom, I saw that I had to define the "group=CPTED_YR" first and then move on to "geom_line", so that is what I did.

Link: [Different line types in one ggplot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722466/different-line-types-in-one-ggplot-graph)

```
SP + geom_vline(xintercept=1000) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(7000, 12000)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("#DC71FA","#FC717F","#7997FF", "#00BBDB"))
+ geom_line(aes(linetype=CPTED_YR))
```

[image]

However, this is what I got. A total catastrophe. I have suffered it once when I forgot to change the CPTED_YR as text (string) not a number (integer). This time, I didn't forget to change it, so I think something else is causing an issue right now.

Please let me know how to change the line type, and if I can set each line type manually, also please tell me how to do so.

Shawn, you asked for the reproductible dataset using dput() so here is a 20 rows extraction using dput(). Thanks!

```
structure(list(OBJECTID = c(8L, 15L, 29L, 43L, 52L, 72L, 96L, 
115L, 116L, 117L), Care_500m = c(0L, 391L, 0L, 185L, 296L, 0L, 
279L, 262L, 262L, 262L), Kind_500m = c(284L, 0L, 161L, 344L, 
155L, 161L, 219L, 269L, 269L, 269L), Elem_500m = c(0L, 652L, 
630L, 521L, 652L, 630L, 667L, 521L, 521L, 521L), Midl_500m = c(0L, 
553L, 757L, 0L, 1310L, 757L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), High_500m = c(0L, 
0L, 2182L, 0L, 0L, 2182L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Area = c(76.16, 77.49, 
76.832, 57.9, 67.67, 68.25, 63.17, 79.735, 79.735, 74.425), Land_Area = c(42.3, 
33, 53.74, 26.59, 52.9, 26.2, 62, 44.5, 44.5, 41.5), Floor = c(3L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), YY.MM = c("2010. 01", "2010. 01", 
"2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", 
"2010. 01", "2010. 01"), Constructe = c(2002L, 1981L, 1998L, 
2001L, 1979L, 2000L, 1979L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L), Age = c(8L, 
29L, 12L, 9L, 31L, 10L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Age.2 = c(64L, 841L, 
144L, 81L, 961L, 100L, 961L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Price_1000 = c(9100L, 
8700L, 10200L, 8700L, 7200L, 8800L, 11650L, 11700L, 11700L, 10900L
), CPI_Price = c(10114.03294, 9669.460066, 11336.60835, 9669.460066, 
8002.311779, 9780.603285, 12948.18503, 13003.75664, 13003.75664, 
12114.61089), CPI_Sqm = c(132.7998023, 124.7833277, 147.5506085, 
167.0027645, 118.2549398, 143.3055426, 204.973643, 163.0871843, 
163.0871843, 162.7760952), LM.PRICE. = c(9.221679139, 9.176727751, 
9.335792446, 9.176727751, 8.987485751, 9.188156447, 9.468710905, 
9.472993567, 9.472993567, 9.402167515), CPTED_YR = structure(c(13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("-6", 
"-5", "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "999"
), class = "factor"), YR_D3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), YR_D2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), YR_D1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), YR_D0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), YR_A1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), YR_A2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), YR_A3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AFTER = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D0_D100 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BEF_D100 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AFT_D100 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), D100_D200 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), AFT_D200 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CPTED_DIST = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), CBD_DIST = c(11991.09961, 
8773.040039, 8964.610352, 9999.160156, 8633.870117, 8891.290039, 
8332.209961, 10094.90039, 10094.90039, 10094.90039), SBWY_DIST = c(2933.48999, 
148.5440063, 384.4899902, 475.1059875, 153.1179962, 390.7319946, 
606.9630127, 386.1149902, 386.1149902, 386.1149902), EMD = c(33L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L), SIG = c("Gangseo", 
"Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", 
"Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong"), POP_YR = c(22618, 
57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399
), DONG_AREA = c(14.1615, 6.2785802, 6.2785802, 6.2785802, 6.2785802, 
6.2785802, 6.2785802, 6.2785802, 6.2785802, 6.2785802), INC_YR = c(240.9638554, 
269.629109, 269.629109, 269.629109, 269.629109, 269.629109, 269.629109, 
269.629109, 269.629109, 269.629109)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I have added a 20-row dataset, but it seems too long with un-related variables appearing. I should creat something else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the `dput`, but I'm guessing some information was lost in the subset you gave because I'm unable to reproduce it. For example `CPTED_DIST` only goes to -1 here when I glimpse the data:

```
Rows: 10
Columns: 39
$ OBJECTID   <int> 8, 15, 29, 43, 52, 72, 96, 115, 116, 117
$ Care_500m  <int> 0, 391, 0, 185, 296, 0, 279, 262, 262, 262
$ Kind_500m  <int> 284, 0, 161, 344, 155, 161, 219, 269, 269, 269
$ Elem_500m  <int> 0, 652, 630, 521, 652, 630, 667, 521, 521, 521
$ Midl_500m  <int> 0, 553, 757, 0, 1310, 757, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ High_500m  <int> 0, 0, 2182, 0, 0, 2182, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ Area       <dbl> 76.160, 77.490, 76.832, 57.900, 67.670, 68.250, 63.…
$ Land_Area  <dbl> 42.30, 33.00, 53.74, 26.59, 52.90, 26.20, 62.00, 44…
$ Floor      <int> 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4
$ YY.MM      <chr> "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "2010. 01", "20…
$ Constructe <int> 2002, 1981, 1998, 2001, 1979, 2000, 1979, 2009, 200…
$ Age        <int> 8, 29, 12, 9, 31, 10, 31, 1, 1, 1
$ Age.2      <int> 64, 841, 144, 81, 961, 100, 961, 1, 1, 1
$ Price_1000 <int> 9100, 8700, 10200, 8700, 7200, 8800, 11650, 11700, …
$ CPI_Price  <dbl> 10114.033, 9669.460, 11336.608, 9669.460, 8002.312,…
$ CPI_Sqm    <dbl> 132.7998, 124.7833, 147.5506, 167.0028, 118.2549, 1…
$ LM.PRICE.  <dbl> 9.221679, 9.176728, 9.335792, 9.176728, 8.987486, 9…
$ CPTED_YR   <fct> 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999
$ YR_D3      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_D2      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_D1      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_D0      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_A1      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_A2      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ YR_A3      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ AFTER      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ D0_D100    <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ BEF_D100   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ AFT_D100   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ D100_D200  <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ AFT_D200   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ CPTED_DIST <dbl> -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
$ CBD_DIST   <dbl> 11991.10, 8773.04, 8964.61, 9999.16, 8633.87, 8891.…
$ SBWY_DIST  <dbl> 2933.490, 148.544, 384.490, 475.106, 153.118, 390.7…
$ EMD        <int> 33, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38
$ SIG        <chr> "Gangseo", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "Geumjeong", "…
$ POP_YR     <dbl> 22618, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57399, 57…
$ DONG_AREA  <dbl> 14.16150, 6.27858, 6.27858, 6.27858, 6.27858, 6.278…
$ INC_YR     <dbl> 240.9639, 269.6291, 269.6291, 269.6291, 269.6291, 2…
```

I can provide an example with another dataset if that is helpful.

I'm thinking your issue is that you are using `geom_line` rather than `geom_smooth` (you used this in your first example and I think it makes sense to do in your second plot as well). The `geom_line` function draws a line to the next proximal point, whereas `geom_smooth` tries to run either an OLS regression line or loess regression line through the data. Here is an example of `geom_line` and how messy it looks:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,
             y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Species,
                  color=Species),
              se=F)
```

[image]

Versus `geom_smooth`:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,
             y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype=Species,
                  color=Species),
              se=F)
```

Seen below, where I have changed both the color and the linetype of each line:

[image]

I also tried to loosely simulate your data and made a similar plot below, which you can of course switch out for your values in your data:

```
df <- data.frame(CPTED_DIST = rnorm(n=1000,
                                    mean=1000,
                                    sd=100),
                 CPI_Price = rnorm(n=1000,
                                   mean=9000),
                 CPTED_YR = as.factor(rbinom(n=1000,
                                   size=3,
                                   prob=.5)))
unique(df$CPTED_YR)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=CPTED_DIST,
             y=CPI_Price))+
  geom_smooth(se=F,
              data = filter(df, CPTED_YR==2),
                  aes(color = CPTED_YR),
              linetype = "longdash")+
  geom_smooth(se=F,
              data = filter(df, CPTED_YR==1),
              aes(color = CPTED_YR),
              linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_smooth(se=F,
              data = filter(df, CPTED_YR==0),
              aes(color = CPTED_YR),
              linetype = "solid")+
  geom_smooth(se=F,
              data = filter(df, CPTED_YR==3),
              aes(color = CPTED_YR),
              linetype = "twodash")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1000)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue",
                              "navyblue",
                              "red",
                              "brown"))
```

Which gives you this (I turned of the SE of each line btw because its distracting for the data I used):

[image]

Let me know if this is similar to what you are looking for and if not I can amend my answer.